# python read file from current line

Tags: python, file-read

I have one problem regarding using python to process the trace file (it contains billion lines of data).

What I want to do is, the program will find one specific line in the file (say it is line# x), and it needs to find another symbol from this (line# x) in the file. Once it finds the line, starts from (line# x) again to search another one.

What I did now, is as following, but the problem is it always needs to reopen the file and read from the beginning to find the match ones (line # > x, and contain the symbol I want). For one big trace file, it takes too long to processing.

1.

```
    for line in file.readlines()
      i++ #update the line number
      if i > x:
          if (line.find()):
```

or:

```
   for i, line in enumerate(open(file)):
      if i > x:
          if ....
```

Anyone can give me one hint on better ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is otherwise stable, use [`fileobj.tell()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to remember your position in the file, then next time use [`fileobj.seek(pos)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to return to that same position in the file.

This only works if you do *not* use the fileobject as an iterator (no `for line in fileobject)` or `next(fileobject)`) as that uses a read-ahead buffer that will obscure the exact position.

Instead, use:

```
for line in iter(fileobj.readline, ''):
```

to still use `fileobj` in an iteration context.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use random access, and record where your line started. Something like:

```
index = []

fh = open(gash.txt)

for line in fh:
    if target in line:
        index.append(fh.tell() - len(line))
```

Then, when you want to recall the contents, use `fh.seek(index[n])`.

A couple of "gotchas":

1. Notice that the index position will not be the same as the line number.  If you need the line number then maybe use a dictionary, with the line number as the key.
2. On Windows, you will have to adjust the file position by -1.  This is because the "\r" is stripped out and does not appear in the `len(line)`.

Comment: This is not going to be accurate. `for line in fh` uses `fh` as an iterator, at which point the file is read in large (order of several kilobytes) blocks. `fh.tell()` will jump along with those larger buffer reads.

Comment: Besides, why not use the *previous* call to `fh.tell()` to determine where a line started? Why subtract `len(line)` *at all*?